# move global react component based on page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-three-fiber

I have a global three.js canvas in next that I want to be on every page and preserve its state between pages. However, I want to move and scale it when the page transitions with framer motion. So my `_app.js` looks something like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Background />
            <AnimateSharedLayout>
                <motion.div layoutId="header">
                    <Header />
                </motion.div>
            </AnimateSharedLayout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Where should I put css code to modify the position of the header div depending on the page? I tried giving the `<motion.div>` a `className` and using css modules to edit the `top` property, but it doesn't seem like the style is applying. I also tried giving it an `id` and using `document.getElementById().style += "top: 30%"` but that didn't seem to move it either.

What's the best way to get my header component to move on a page transition while not re-rendering the component?

Comment: You can keep reference `React.createRef()`, then on `componentDidMount` of new pages modify CSS, properties of that. Also, can use context API for that.